# Are these results for a loaded beam reasonable?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am studying mechanical engineering and decided to write an FEM solver for structural mechanical problems. I implemented linear and quadratic elements in 2D and 3D. I wanted to look at my results and decided to write some visualiser in python.

I build a small testing case:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Looking at the deformation plot ($\sqrt{d_x+d_y}$, the result looks reasonable:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

The Von-Mises stresses do look more interesting.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

You can see a clear thin line starting at the point where the force is applied to the bottom right in an 40° angle. The stresses here seem to be significant lower. I decided to look into the different parts of the Von-Mises stresses.

---

### $\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}$

### [![enter image description here][4]][4]

### $\sqrt{\sigma_{xy}^2}$

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

Are these results expected? I assume, due to the force being applied to a single node, I see a superposition of a bending beam and a concentrated pressing onto a surface. Is my assumption correct or do you think, that these results are unlikely?

Greetings
Finn
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPEXh.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f77b.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4sL0.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBwSR.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2l1T.png

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/669620/2451